# I want to deserialize JSON with the structure given below into the given Java Class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to read the given JSON format using Jackson into the Student class, which contains a set of object of another class Details.java

How to do this parsing?

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
Student student = = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_INPUT, Student.class);
```

JSON

```
{

    "studentName": Mikhael,
    "studentID": 251,
    "details": [  
         {"detail1": value1, detail2: value2},
         {"detail1": value3, detail2: value4}
     ] 

}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    private String studentName;
    private int studentID;
    private Set<Details> details;

    public Student(String studentName, Integer studentID, Set<Details> details){
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.details = details;
    }

}
```

Details.java

```
public class Details {

    private String detail1;
    private String detail2;

    public Details(String detail1, String detail2){
        this.detail1 = detail1;
        this.detail2 = detail2;
    }

}
```

Comment: The first code snippet is what I have thought but I am not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an option I would use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. It uses reflection so it needs no setters to populate the data. And it won't use that constructors either.

With that library you can do the deserialization in just one line as you have previously defined `Student` and `Details` classes with properties that match:

```
Student studentObject = new Gson().fromJson(JSON_INPUT, Student.class);
```

Then you'll need to add some getters to get the data of studentObject.

**Update**

I think I've also found what is wrong with that Jackson ObjectMapper you used. According to [this site](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not) Jackson works different and if the field is non public like those ones you have to define setters or getters and the library will use them.

A setter makes a non-public field deserializable only whereas a getter makes a non-public field serializable and deserializable.

So you need to add setters or getters for studentName, studentID, details, detail1 & detail2 if you still prefer using jackson or it won't work.